# What's the right pattern to follow for an Altjs + ReactRouter project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-alt

I started my first react app following this [SurviveJS](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/introduction/) brilliant guide to develop a kanban app. This involves [altjs](http://alt.js.org/) as flux technology, really simple to use.

The author suggests to use an [AltContainer](http://alt.js.org/docs/components/altContainer/) to link store(s) to the component(s), an easy solution that will transform your App component (the root one) into something like this:

```js
/* ... */

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <AltContainer
          stores={[MyStoreOne]}
          inject={{
            myProps: () => MyStoreOne.getState().myProps
          }}
        >
          <ComponentOne/>
        </AltContainer>
        <AltContainer
          stores={[MyStoreTwo]}
          inject={{
            myProps: () => MyStoreTwo.getState().myProps
          }}
        >
          <ComponentTwo/>
        </AltContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The question now is: when I use a react router what's the best way to let AltContainers work with their linked components, considering a [nested routes](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes) approach?

```js
/* ... */
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="/one/:paramOne" component={ComponentOne}/>
      <Route path="/two/:paramTwo" component={ComponentTwo}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('knots'));
```

Where I have to put my AltContainers, now that the components are called directly from the router (and not from the App)?

Moving the flux logic directly inside the subcomponents (so avoiding AltContainers) is antipattern?

Comment: I started going through the same tutorials as you are. Now I'm building a much bigger React/Alt application. I'm not using AltContainers in my app. I didn't see the need. I have `componentWillMount() {
        QuestionStore.listen(this.onChange);
    }` to listen for store changes and update accordingly

Comment: Oh well, I'll try that way, thanks!